question about including an independent variable
I'm seeking advice on whether to include the independent variable 'smoking' (Yes/No) in my analysis.
The objective is to examine the impact of COVID-19 on female construction workers. The outcome variable is whether the subject (female construction worker) was employed during COVID-19 (Yes/No).
The dataset comprises data from 13 randomly recruited locations across the US, all exclusively consisting of women.
As is, the variable 'smoking status' (Yes/No) is highly imbalanced (90% No, 10% Yes). When performing a simple bivariate analysis , smoking status vs site of work (13 locations across the US), a crosstable of Site vs Smoking shows that the majority of women (associated with 10 sites) reported 'No' to smoking, with only random variations in responses among women in the remaining 3 sites.
In theory there is a strong relation between smoking and employed(Yes/No) during COVID. However given the highly imbalanced nature of this variable, I'm deliberating whether to include the variable 'smoking status' in my analysis.
Your advise or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

First, if the objective is to look at the impact of COVID on female construction workers, then you will also need data from before COVID. It's not clear if you have that, but it looks like you don't.  Second, how is smoking nested within site? Third, I don't understand your sentence starting "I found ..."

@PeterFlom, I have updated my question description based on your questions. Is this helpful ? Please pardon my ignorance if I am missing somethings here.

I'd expect smoking/nonsmoking to vary by individual, regardless of site.  Thus I wouldn't treat it as a nested variable but instead as a "fixed effect."

@rolando2, I agree. That sentence "nested within site" is mislead. I have removed that sentence.

What does the imbalance have to do with anything?

@Dave, makes smoking=No for women in 10 Sites

What is your model? You have only mentioned two variables: working during COVID and smoking.

@Noah, Binomial Yes/No. One row per subject. There are other job related variables.

Nothing in your post gives any reason why you shouldn't include smoking as a predictor. Do you think only predictors with a proportion close to .5 are allowed in regression models?

@Noah, good point Noah. I was just wondering if there is any use in including a predictor that is so one dimensional (90% No) , to a point where , I start wondering about what new information it can provide beyond what we already know ?

Isn't that the empirical question you are trying to answer? Does smoking explain enough variability in the outcome to be useful as a predictor?

I think there are some problems with your design.
If your objective is to examine the effect of COVID 19 on employment for women construction workers then you would need data from before and during COVID (you seem to have just during) and I think you would want data on women and men (you say you have just women).
Without before and during, you can't look at the change during COVID.
And, while you could look at the change in employment for women without looking at men, that would not be very interesting, at least to me. I think what you probably want to do is compare women to men: Did they lose jobs at a higher or lower rate than men did?
As to smoking being only 10%, that doesn't really matter if the overall sample is really big. BUT while smoking may well be related to employment, is it related to change in employment? Did smokers get fired first? Or, since tobacco use was (IIRC) a risk factor for more serious COVID symptoms, did they quit more often?

excellent point, I will skip the 1st part and jump to the smoking. Whether smokers were fired, laidoff, or lost hours temporarily is part of the question in this analysis.
